# Login users from multiple Azure AD's in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, azure, security, authentication

I've got a Java Spring Security project that's linked to an Azure AD via a registered Application. This way I can redirect users to Microsoft to login with their Azure account before being able to view certain pages or use certain endpoints. This is all working great.

The problem is, I have another AD (and possibly more in the future) that I also want to be able to have users log into. However as far as I can see Spring Security only allows for 1 AD to be configured, so when a user wants to log in they always have to be a part of the currently linked AD.

I've tried looking into different solutions for this, for example syncing all the users from the external AD into the active AD. For this I was able to retrieve a list of users, but when I wanted to add them to the AD, the only API endpoints I could find were to create new accounts instead of link them from an external AD. Another idea was to configure Spring Security to simply authenticate against more than 1 AD. But as far as I've seen, that's not possible.

In the end I just want to have a situation where users from both AD's can log into my application, using their existing credentials without me having to manually invite each and every one. What is the best practice when dealing with a situation like this? I'd very much appreciate some help pointing me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could look at making the application multi-tenant.. read about it here.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant

Comment: Remember multi-tenant apps mean any tenant can log in. You have to check on your back-end what tenant was used to log in, and block them if they used one you don't want. Unless you of course want any tenant to be able to sign in :)

Comment: Yes that's a good point from @juunas as usual.. Making the app multi-tenant may get you out of *having to manually invite each and every one* but you will need to put some effort to implement it correctly, like using /common endppoint, validating the tenant, understanding the consent framework and permissions you need and so on.. so read through and see if it makes sense.. good luck!

Comment: That sounds very promising! I'm going to look into the page you linked and multi-tenant applications in general. Having to do some more effort on the back-end shouldn't be an issue, as long as it accomplishes my goal. Thanks!